# Anchor only solana build error ( fine with cargo )

Tags: anchor, cargo, build-bpf, build-sbf, failed

When I compile my code with
`cargo build-sbf` or `cargo test-sbf` I get no issues.

But when I build with anchor build I get

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `crate::sys::IoSourceState`
  --> src/io_source.rs:12:5
   |
12 | use crate::sys::IoSourceState;
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no `IoSourceState` in `sys`

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: could not find `Selector` in `sys`
   --> src/poll.rs:354:18
    |
354 |             sys::Selector::new().map(|selector| Poll {
    |                  ^^^^^^^^ could not find `Selector` in `sys`
```

Solana version 1.16.3 ( CLI and deps )

Ubuntu

Rustc 1.71.0

Anchor 0.28 ( CLI and deps )

Seems like the error comes from the mio 0.7.14 package.

Comment: Can you provide some more information about your program? Probably the `Cargo.toml` would be the biggest help